# Column not found in Left Join

Tags: java, mysql, sql, join, jdbc

```
    "SELECT `articles`.`name`, `articles`.`description`,`articles`.`startPrice`,`articles`.`creationDate`," 
                        + "`bids`.`date`, `bids`.`price`,`bids`.`userId`"
                        + " FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `bids` ON `articles`.`id` = `bids`.`articleId`"
                        + " WHERE 1"
```

> java.sql.SQLException: Column '`articles`.`id`' not found.

`bids` table has not records, but just wanted to try that, since I understand that the Left Join shows all the records in the table on the left although the right table has no records.

I have changed Left Join by Inner Join and the query runs without errors
with result of zero records (as expected).

MySql version is 5.7.18

articles table:

[image]

**Some Test:**

Example of a query that work Ok without errors:

```
"select `articles`.`id`, `articles`.`name`, `articles`.`description`,`articles`.`startPrice`,`articles`.`creationDate`," + 
"`bids`.`date`, `bids`.`price`,`bids`.`userId`"
                                + " FROM `articles` INNER JOIN `bids` ON  `articles`.`id` = `bids`.`articleId` "
                                + " WHERE 1"
```

I also try to restart my MySql server and the same thing happens

I am using java and JDBC with

```
statement.executeQuery()
```

Comment: are your sure you have a column named id in articels table ??

Comment: Yes, exists. If I change Left Join by Inner join query works.

Comment: What if you add articles.id to your columns? Any difference?

Comment: If I add `articles`.`id` to my Select columns exactly the same error occurs. But if in addition to that, if I change the Left Join By inner join the query works with `articles`.`id`

Comment: are you able to execute any left joins of any other tables? the only differences in your query are whitespace and the keywords `LEFT` <> `INNER`

Comment: also, your second query includes the id in the `SELECT` clause, which you're already aware of.

Comment: can you also try removing all the backticks? it shouldn't matter, but it might.

Comment: Please post your Java code used to execute this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know why but it was fixed using the Java Statement class instead of PreparedStatement to execute query.

Comment: If this is the answer to your own question, please mark it as such to show other users that this question is answered.

Comment: As it stands, this doesn't really answer the question, your question should contain the original code, and this answer should contain the code that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"SELECT `articles`.`name`, `articles`.`description`,`articles`.`startPrice`,`articles`.`creationDate`," 
                        + "`bids`.`date`, `bids`.`price`,`bids`.`userId`"
                        + " FROM `articles` LEFT JOIN `bids` ON  `bids`.`articleId` = `articles`.`id`"
                        + " WHERE 1"
```

Comment: Yes, I have tested it by inverting the conditions of clause On with the same results.